# Restoring an RDS Instance to a backup/snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to **RESTORE** an RDS instance to one of it's previous backups/snapshots, but when I follow the provided instructions by Amazon it **CREATES** a new instance from the backup instead of restoring the existing one.

I would like to just restore the db to an existing state because I have an EC2 instance pointing to it (managed through  a Load Balancer) that I'd prefer to not have to go in and point to the new RDS.

How can I restore an RDS instance back to a previous point in time **AND NOT** create a new instance from the backup/snapshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon RDS: Restore snapshot to existing instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278220/amazon-rds-restore-snapshot-to-existing-instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restore to new RDS instance. Then rename or original rds server to something else and apply change immediately. Once the change is processed (2-3 min), rename the restore instance to the same name as the original rds and apply immediately.

RDS dns name within single account only varies by initial part, which is taken from the RDS instance name.

Comment: Not the perfect solution, but it is the best one we have as of now. Another option would be to dump data out of the new instance and add it to the old one. For example - mysqldump -> mysqlrestore

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is you can't:

> You can't restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new
> DB instance is created when you restore.

from here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have terraform experience, I found this to be the most reproducible way of restoring from snapshots.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "prod" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}

data "aws_db_snapshot" "latest_prod_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.prod.id
  most_recent            = true
}

# Use the latest production snapshot to create a dev instance.
resource "aws_db_instance" "dev" {
  instance_class      = "db.t2.micro"
  name                = "mydbdev"
  snapshot_identifier = data.aws_db_snapshot.latest_prod_snapshot.id

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [snapshot_identifier]
  }
}
```

[From the terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_snapshot).