# Amazon RDS: Restore rds snapshot to existing instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have created a snapshot of my instance and made some unwanted changes in DB.

Now I want to restore my instance from this snapshot.

When I try to do it - it creates me one more instance, additionally to the one I have.

I specify "DB Instance Identifier" and after that I get two instances with the same ID.

So my question: Is there any way to restore snapshot to existing instance?

Because in other case - new instance is created with differrent endpoint (hostname) and I need to change my configs to access database. Or there is a better way to manage such cases?

I see a post in 2014 which said it is not possible, but now is it possible?

[Amazon RDS: Restore snapshot to existing instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278220/amazon-rds-restore-snapshot-to-existing-instance)

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore RDS snapshot to an existing instance. [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) is explicit on this issue:

> You can't restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new
> DB instance is created when you restore.